# URL Routing in NOP Commerce

Tags: nopcommerce

I am trying to figure out how this works, for example if I pull up a category page: http://localhost:15536/desktops it hits the following Action method in the CatalogController:

`public virtual IActionResult Category(int categoryId, CatalogPagingFilteringModel command)`

So how it's passing in the correct category id (int) but it's not part of the URL how does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Nopcommerce, there is an entity named `UrlRecord`, you can find it in Nop.Core\Domain\Seo\UrlRecord.cs:

```
public partial class UrlRecord : BaseEntity
{
    public int EntityId { get; set; }

    public string EntityName { get; set; }

    public string Slug { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public int LanguageId { get; set; }
}
```

The `EntityName`, indicates that this `UrlRecord` is using for which entity (i.g. Product or Category, etc.). The `EntityId` indicates that the `Id` of pointed entity (i.g. `Id` of `Product`). The `Slug` indicates that with what URL we can reach the intended entity. In your example, `EntityName` is "Category", `EntityId` is the `Id` of the category and `Slug` is "desktop".

So, how Nopcommerce routes these `Slug`s to the right Controller and Action? For figuring out of this, we have to look at the `GenericPathRoute` class that is located in Nop.Web.Framework\Seo\GenericPathRoute.cs. This class is registered as a custom `Route` to the `IRouteBuilder`. Regardless of asp.net core routing and Nopcommerce details, the `RouteAsync` method of `GenericPathRoute` is called at the start of every request. If we take a look into this method, we could see this section (before this section, `urlRecord` is fetched from the database by the `Slug`, so we know what is the entity and its `Id`, so we can route it to the desired Controller and Action with right arguments):

```
var currentRouteData = new RouteData(context.RouteData);
switch (urlRecord.EntityName.ToLowerInvariant())
{
    case "product":
        currentRouteData.Values[NopPathRouteDefaults.ControllerFieldKey] = "Product";
        currentRouteData.Values[NopPathRouteDefaults.ActionFieldKey] = "ProductDetails";
        currentRouteData.Values[NopPathRouteDefaults.ProductIdFieldKey] = urlRecord.EntityId;
        currentRouteData.Values[NopPathRouteDefaults.SeNameFieldKey] = urlRecord.Slug;
        break;
    case "producttag":
        currentRouteData.Values[NopPathRouteDefaults.ControllerFieldKey] = "Catalog";
        currentRouteData.Values[NopPathRouteDefaults.ActionFieldKey] = "ProductsByTag";
        currentRouteData.Values[NopPathRouteDefaults.ProducttagIdFieldKey] = urlRecord.EntityId;
        currentRouteData.Values[NopPathRouteDefaults.SeNameFieldKey] = urlRecord.Slug;
        break;
    case "category":
        currentRouteData.Values[NopPathRouteDefaults.ControllerFieldKey] = "Catalog";
        currentRouteData.Values[NopPathRouteDefaults.ActionFieldKey] = "Category";
        currentRouteData.Values[NopPathRouteDefaults.CategoryIdFieldKey] = urlRecord.EntityId;
        currentRouteData.Values[NopPathRouteDefaults.SeNameFieldKey] = urlRecord.Slug;
        break;
    case "manufacturer":
        currentRouteData.Values[NopPathRouteDefaults.ControllerFieldKey] = "Catalog";
        currentRouteData.Values[NopPathRouteDefaults.ActionFieldKey] = "Manufacturer";
        currentRouteData.Values[NopPathRouteDefaults.ManufacturerIdFieldKey] = urlRecord.EntityId;
        currentRouteData.Values[NopPathRouteDefaults.SeNameFieldKey] = urlRecord.Slug;
        break;
    case "vendor":
        currentRouteData.Values[NopPathRouteDefaults.ControllerFieldKey] = "Catalog";
        currentRouteData.Values[NopPathRouteDefaults.ActionFieldKey] = "Vendor";
        currentRouteData.Values[NopPathRouteDefaults.VendorIdFieldKey] = urlRecord.EntityId;
        currentRouteData.Values[NopPathRouteDefaults.SeNameFieldKey] = urlRecord.Slug;
        break;
    case "newsitem":
        currentRouteData.Values[NopPathRouteDefaults.ControllerFieldKey] = "News";
        currentRouteData.Values[NopPathRouteDefaults.ActionFieldKey] = "NewsItem";
        currentRouteData.Values[NopPathRouteDefaults.NewsItemIdFieldKey] = urlRecord.EntityId;
        currentRouteData.Values[NopPathRouteDefaults.SeNameFieldKey] = urlRecord.Slug;
        break;
    case "blogpost":
        currentRouteData.Values[NopPathRouteDefaults.ControllerFieldKey] = "Blog";
        currentRouteData.Values[NopPathRouteDefaults.ActionFieldKey] = "BlogPost";
        currentRouteData.Values[NopPathRouteDefaults.BlogPostIdFieldKey] = urlRecord.EntityId;
        currentRouteData.Values[NopPathRouteDefaults.SeNameFieldKey] = urlRecord.Slug;
        break;
    case "topic":
        currentRouteData.Values[NopPathRouteDefaults.ControllerFieldKey] = "Topic";
        currentRouteData.Values[NopPathRouteDefaults.ActionFieldKey] = "TopicDetails";
        currentRouteData.Values[NopPathRouteDefaults.TopicIdFieldKey] = urlRecord.EntityId;
        currentRouteData.Values[NopPathRouteDefaults.SeNameFieldKey] = urlRecord.Slug;
        break;
    default:
        //no record found, thus generate an event this way developers could insert their own types
        EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IEventPublisher>()
            ?.Publish(new CustomUrlRecordEntityNameRequestedEvent(currentRouteData, urlRecord));
        break;
}
context.RouteData = currentRouteData;
```

We can see here that it changes the routeData of this request, regarding `EntityName`. We can see here that this feature is going to work only for entities named in this switch/case command.

Comment: I really appreciate you reviewing all of this, extremely helpful information!